# How should the version look when artifacts are relased?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

I'm working on my project's versioning and I want to adopt the guidelines from [here](https://semver.org/#semantic-versioning-200).

I just have one question that either I didn't get or the material didn't cover. How should the release version look?

My understanding is that having a pre-release label is for internal development, as well as the build metadata. When building the artifacts for a release version, should you strip all the labels and keeping only the `version core`, i.e.: `major.minor.patch`? What label could get into source control and which **must** never do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the spec](https://semver.org/), there are release and prerelease versions. A release version does not have zero for the major field or have a prerelease tag attached. You are free to do whatever you like with regards to build-meta.

In the real world, a "release" is anything you've published, such that it is publicly available. So for internal use, do what you want, but for external use, follow the spec. In other words, you can release a prerelease version by publishing it.